# Why do I get Bootstrap integrity problems

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I get the folowing problem when I try to run my PHP file

Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' with computed SHA-512 integrity 'b2QcS5SsA8tZodcDtGRELiGv5SaKSk1vDHDaQRda0htPYWZ6046lr3kJ5bAAQdpV2mmA/4v0wQF9MyU6/pDIAg=='. The resource has been blocked.

```
<?php include '../php/signUp.php';?>
<!--Inkluderar php filen i html filen-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Definierar dokumenttypen för HTML5 -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Tentahubb">
<!-- Ange titeln som visas på Apple-enheter när webbappen är installerad på startsidan -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="">
<!-- Ange ikonen som används när användare lägger till webbappen på hemskärmen på en Apple-enhet -->
<html lang="sv">
<!-- Öppna HTML-dokumentet med språkkoden för svenska -->
<head>
    <!-- Öppna sidhuvudet -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Ange visningsinställningarna för responsivt beteende på olika enheter -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Ange teckenkodningen för dokumentet som UTF-8 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Ange Internet Explorer-kompatibilitetsläge -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Ange visningsinställningarna för responsivt beteende på olika enheter -->

    <title>Tentahub</title>
    <!-- Ange sidans titel -->

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- Tillåt att webbappen visas som en fristående app på mobila enheter -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- Tillåt att webbappen visas som en fristående app på Apple-enheter -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!-- Ange färgen på statusfältet på Apple-enheter -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="../manifest.json">
    <!-- Länka till manifestfilen för progressiv webbapp (PWA) -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="c9bc73">
    <!-- Ange färgtemat för webbappen -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="c9bc73">
    <!-- Ange färgen på Windows-flisen för webbappen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Tentahub">
    <!-- Ange titeln som visas på Apple-enheter när webbappen är installerad på startsidan -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="">
    <!-- Ange ikonen som används när användare lägger till webbappen på hemskärmen på en Apple-enhet -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="" />
    <!-- Ange den kanoniska länken för att undvika duplicerat innehåll -->

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Tentahub" />
    <!-- Ange webbplatsens namn för Open Graph-protokollet -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <!-- Ange typen av objekt för Open Graph-protokollet -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Tentahub" />
    <!-- Ange titeln för Open Graph-protokollet -->
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="Tentahub" />
    <!-- Ange titeln för Twitter-kortet -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <!-- Ange URL:en för Open Graph-protokollet -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <!-- Ange bilden för Open Graph-protokollet -->
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="" />
    <!-- Ange bilden för Twitter-kortet -->
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <!-- Ange typen av Twitter-kort -->

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">-->

    <style>
        <?php
            include "../css/style.css";
        ?>
    </style>

    <!-- Länka till extern CSS-stilmall -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="b2QcS5SsA8tZodcDtGRELiGv5SaKSk1vDHDaQRda0htPYWZ6046lr3kJ5bAAQdpV2mmA/4v0wQF9MyU6/pDIAg==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Länka till extern Bootstrap CSS-stilmall -->

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <!-- Förbered för att ansluta till Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <!-- Förbered för att ansluta till Google Fonts med korsnavigeringstillstånd -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Länka till Google Fonts för League Spartan-typsnittet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
    <!-- Länka till Font Awesome-ikoner med integritetskontroller -->

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- Tillåt att webbappen visas som en fristående app på mobila enheter -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assests/favicons/LINDA_C_Gold_Small.ico" sizes="32x32" />
    <!-- Ange ikonen som visas i webbläsartabben -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assests/favicons/LINDA_C_Gold_Small.ico" />
    <!-- Ange ikonen som används när användare lägger till webbappen på hemskärmen på en Apple-enhet -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <!--Navigerignslista-->
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <button id="hem" class="btn btn-primary">Hem</button>
                <button id="tentor" class="btn btn-primary">Tentor</button> 
                <button id="omoss" class="btn btn-primary">Om oss</button>
                <a href="./signup.php" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
    <aside>
        <div class="container2">
            <!--Formulär för att logga in
            Valideras i signUp.php-->
            <form method="POST" id="loggin">
                <p><?php echo $result?></p>
                <input type="email" name="logginemail" id="logginemail" placeholder="email">
                <p><?php echo $emailErr?></p>
                <input type="password" name="logginpassword" id="logginpassword" placeholder="password">
                <p><?php echo $passwordErr?></p>
                <input type="submit" name="Loggin" value="loggin" class="btn btn-success">      
            </form>
            <a href="./minaSidor.php" class="btn btn-success" id="minaSidor">Mina sidor</a>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!--Visar sidans huvudinnehåll-->
    <main>
        <div class="mainContainer">
            <div id="tenta" >
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type='file' name='pdfFile'>
                    <input type="text" name="skola" placeholder="skola">
                    <input type="text" name="kursnamn" placeholder="kursnamn">
                    <input type="text" name="kurskod" placeholder="kurskod">
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value="ladda upp">
                </form>

                <!-- Formulär för att söka efter tentor
                Formuläret valideras i filen php.php -->
                <form method='POST' id="searchTenta" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type='search' id='inputSearch' placeholder="search" name="search">
                </form>
                <!--Visar resultat från databasen med tentor-->
                <div id="search">
                    <?php
                        include '../php/php.php';
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container3">
            <span class="text-muted">Developed by Linda Carlstad's IT committee, Maintained by <a
                    href="https://lindacarlstad.se">LINDA
                    Carlstad</a> | Vid kontakt eller fel, maila <a href="mit@lindacarlstad.se"><span
                        class="__cf_email__"
                        data-cfemail="066f72466a6f6862676567746a75726762287563">[email&#160;protected]</span></a></span>
            <br>
            <small>Copyright © 2023 - Alla rättigheter reserverade - Studentföreningen
                <a href="https://www.lindacarlstad.se" title="Linda Carlstad">Linda Carlstad</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The integrity string doesn't match what is shown on https://getbootstrap.com/ , so the resource is blocked.